# CannotResolveClassException for ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I was trying to restore jenkins on a new machine by tacking up backup from old machine . I replaced the jenkins home directory of new machine from old one. When i launch jenkins it gives me this error.

```
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
```

There is also

```
 Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
```

Debug info is 
---- Debugging information ----

```
message             : hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
class               : hudson.model.Hudson
required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
path                : /hudson/authorizationStrategy
line number         : 11
version             : not available
-------------------------------
```

This is what my config.xml look like

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
  <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy">
    <permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Administer:visha</permission>
  </authorizationStrategy>
```

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 6):

This usually happens when the plugin providing the authorization strategy is not installed or enabled.

Make sure the `matrix-auth` plugin is installed and that it's not disabled (no `matrix-auth.jpi.disabled` file (or similar) in `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/`).

Comment: I see these files in $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/ 

matrix-project matrix-project.jpi matrix-auth matrix-auth.jpi. When i change the authorization strategy to  "hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy" and remove all <permission> attributes . Jenkins do get started but i don't see any jobs or plugin which i had backed up. P.S : I have same version of jenkins and java installed on both machines

Comment: I had a similar problem and was able to get Jenkins started by renaming the matrix-auth.jpi.disabled file.

Comment: I didn't have this plugin disabled, but I solved this by moving out all disabled files: "sudo mv ./*.disabled ./tmp/."

Answer (score 2):

It can happen if a newer version of a plugin is incompatible with older version of Jenkins. It's recommended to upgrade Jenkins to latest version.

This is how I do it:

```
ssh jenkins "cd /tmp; wget https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/jenkins.war"
ssh jenkins "cp /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war /tmp/jenkins.war.previous.version"
ssh jenkins "sudo systemctl status jenkins"
ssh jenkins "sudo cp /tmp/jenkins.war /usr/share/jenkins/"
ssh jenkins "sudo systemctl restart jenkins"
```

Answer (score 1):

usually, this error ours when there is a mismatch between Jenkins Version and Plugins version.

Best solution is always to keep updated Jenkins and plugin or installed appropriate versions of jenkins according to the Jenkins version.

For centos, Redhat, amazon Linux follow the below steps.

```
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
yum update Jenkins.
```

For an ubuntu machine, you can follow the steps given by hit3k.

```
cd /tmp; wget https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/jenkins.war
cp /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war /tmp/jenkins.war.previous.version
sudo systemctl status jenkins
sudo cp /tmp/jenkins.war /usr/share/jenkins/
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot even log in because of this error, you can disable security in jenkins config file /config.xml.
Search for `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` and change the value to `false`. Then restart jenkins from command line and you should be able to login and make change to plugin/auth configurations as suggested in other answers.

Comment: I did this, logged in and upgraded the matrix auth plugin, copied my old version of the config back, changed the version number in the old file to match the newly generated one (not sure this part mattered), then restarted jenkins. It worked and I didn't have to manually fix all my configuration.

Answer (score 1):

keep the backup of the var/lib/jenkins/config.xml ---> confg.xml.backup

comment this line authorizationStrategy  from config.xml

sudo systemctl stop jenkins

sudo systemctl restart jenkins

open the web and update all the plugins

later from the backup file copy the above permissions what ever you have commented and restart the jenkins you should be able to login